# How to get the class contained by a Vector - Reflection

Tags: java, parsing, reflection

I'm using [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/index.html) to parse a .java file. The file contains a method like this:

`public int getSomething (Vector<Integer> numbers);`

the problem is I don't know how to get the Integer class using the reflection which QDox provides.
Any idea of how can I get it?

Comment: Can you point us to the classes in QDox you are using?  If you are attempting to parse the actual source you should be able to get the type, but attempting to use Java reflection at runtime will not get you the information you want.

Comment: I'm using JavaDocBuilder, JavaClass, JavaMethod, JavaParameter and Type. Type is the class which has the Vector.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the type of a method's parameter your interested in, you can obtain if from the Method:

```
    Method method = myclass.getMethod("getSomething", Vector.class);
    Type atypes[] = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if (atypes[0] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType)atypes[0];
        Type aatypes[] = ptype.getActualTypeArguments();
        System.out.println(aatypes[0]);
    }
```

Comment: The class that has the method `public int getSomething (Vector<Integer> numbers)`

Comment: I believe this answer is for normal reflection (i.e. java.lang.reflect), not for QDox.

Comment: I don't undertand. 
From where is getMethod ?

Comment: My class is com.thoughtworks.qdox.model.Type and it doesn't have that